# Selenium test automate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, selenium, azure-devops, automated-tests

I created a pipeline under azure devops which runs in a vm and which I use to launch selenium tests created from selenium ide

`**pool: vmImage: 'windows-latest'**`

The start of my pipeline is to install the things I need to do this

**  - task: Npm@0
displayName: 'install selenium-side-runner'
inputs:
arguments: 'selenium-side-runner@4.0.0-alpha.34 --global'

`- task: Npm@0 displayName: 'install chromedriver' inputs: arguments: 'chromedriver@108.0.0 --global'**`

and then I run the tests with selenium-side-runner with a command line task

`**- task: CmdLine@2 inputs: script: 'selenium-side-runner Yards.side --timeout 6000000 -c "browserName=chrome" -d' workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Selenium/te**`sts'

the test file is well read and starts trying to connect to the app http://www.toto:2001
and this is my concern I have the error unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I tried to add a task to ping known sites but they can't solve it

being on a temporary vm is a problem to access a site or is it something else?

best regards

pool vmimage
can not connect to the internet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description and the guidance in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops#decide-how-you-will-deploy-and-test-your-app), if you would test the web app deployed on your on-premise server, please use a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) that you install on the target servers. Agents must be configured to run interactively with [auto-logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service) enabled.

Currently, your pipeline is running on the Microsoft-hosted agents with the `vmImage` of `windows-latest`.Microsoft-hosted agent are pre-configured for UI testing and UI tests for both web apps and desktop apps. When using the Microsoft-hosted agent, you should use the Selenium web drivers that are pre-installed on the Windows agents, because they are compatible with the browser versions installed on the Microsoft-hosted agent images.

Kindly take [UI testing considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest) for more informaiton.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the rights to create a self-hosted agent
But from what you say 'Less agents hosted  with vmImage.Microsoft hosted agents windows-latest are preconfigured for UI testing and . When using the Microsoft-hosted agent, you must use the Selenium web drivers pre-installed on Windows agents, as they are compatible with the browser versions installed on Microsoft-hosted agent images.'
So I no longer install my selenium web driver but use the preinstalled one but still the same problem I can't communicate with my website  on which I want to test my interfaces

Comment: Is your website hosted on a cloud App service like Azure and could your app URL be accessible by any machine via the public network? If not, you have to use self-hosted agent as you cannot configure DNS for hosted agents.

Comment: ndeed I changed my test to make a banal connection on google and there it passes
my test url which does not pass is indeed an app hosted on the azure cloud with a specific port 2001
I tried from a public network this url is not accessible thank you for your clarification I understand the problem better
Thank you for your answer, I will see how to solve this problem